# Free command line download manager with queue possibilities on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, download-manager, queue

I am looking for a free command line download manager with queue possibilities on Windows XP.

This looks like it might work but it's not free:

> http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/command_line.html

I am currently using Flashget but the command line doesn't have the queue option, so Flashget misses many URLs that are sent to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `wget` together with a script which reads from a named pipe was my first idea...but I'm not sure if that would be easily possible using the cmd.

Comment: @Bobby: However, it is possible using Cygwin + bash.

Comment: @petersohn: I meant that I know how to use a named pipe in Bash, and that I have no idea if it would be *easy* to do the same in (maybe pure) cmd.

Comment: Pssst... there's a typo in the question that should be fixed: donwload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) seems to be the best tool. There are a windows version, I use a text file as queue, you can invoque wget -i file-list.txt. Read the documentation or the help to know the parameters to control the downloads, recoverring, etc.

Comment: Hello, Thanks you very much. Alas I cannot use a "text file as queue". The software should create the queue by itself in my case.

Comment: Hello, finally I have found a way to use a "test file as queue". I am now using VisualWget http://khomsanph.net/visualwget/ Thanks to all for your help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**aria2** might be the best solution. It have a lot of extra features as well and extremely easy to use.

> https://aria2.github.io

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).